# How do I position a video tag in a fixed position?

Tags: html

I have the following video tag:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls id="mainVideo" name="mainVideo">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and I would like to position it on the top right of the browser's screen, irregardless of where the window scroll is (meaning, the video stays on top).

Comment: A quick search would suggest using `style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;"` - why didn't you try that, or why did it not work?

Comment: Also, why do you hate your users? :D

Comment: thanks! the "position:fixed" was what I was missing... and really, this is for good causes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
#mainVideo{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  }
```